# .unbind('submit').submit() works in Chrome/IE but doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have the following javascript code using jquery 1.9.1:

```
(function ($) {
$(function () {
    eventTracking();
});

function eventTracking() {
    $("[data-formtracking]").bind('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var eventName = $(this).data("formtracking");
        rt.trackEvent(eventName);
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
}})(jQuery);
```

Now, when I submit the form, it should make an update to a database, and then follow the action that is on the form, and basically redirect us to the other page.

In Chrome/IE the rt.trackEvent successfully fires and I get redirected to the other site. In Firefox, I get redirected to the other site, but no database entry.

If I add console.log between each statement, I can see that it is hits all of the log statements.

So at this point....I'm baffled. I've tried switching from bind to on/off. I've tried:  $('input[type=submit]', this).click() based on a passing comment on another stackoverflow page.

A few notes:
* rt is in an external file. I've checked and it does exist
* If I remove the unbind.submit, then the rt.trackEvent works correctly, except the page doesn't redirect (obviously).
* I've change the unbind.submit() to other variations, but then I have to click the button twice before it submits.

Thoughts?

**Updated**

The reason for the e.preventDefault() and later submission is that the form submission was happening too quickly. The page would redirect before rt.trackEvent would work properly. So I needed to slow the method down by adding a setTimeout($(this).unbind('submit').submit(), 2000);

I removed this to simplify the code, but in hindset it is pretty essential for the working of the code.

**Updated 2**
Here is the json that is being called:

```
        options = $.extend({ success: $.noop, error: $.noop, urlBuilder: getNoCookieRequestURL, eventName: null }, options);

        options.url = options.urlBuilder(options.url, options.siteId, options.eventName);
        $.getJSON(options.url, function (jsonp) {
            options.success(jsonp);
        }).fail(function () {
            options.error();
        });
```

**Updated 3**

Change getJson to:

```
            options = $.extend({ success: $.noop, error: $.noop, urlBuilder: getNoCookieRequestURL, eventName: null }, options);

        options.url = options.urlBuilder(options.url, options.siteId, options.eventName);

        $.ajax({
            url: options.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function (jsonp) {
                options.success(jsonp);
            },
            error: function() {
                options.error();
            }
        });
```

I still seem to be having the speed issue. Code works when I step through it in Chrome, but database doesn't get updated properly when I just run it.

Comment: You could surely just do `this.submit()` in order to bypass the jQuery handler. I have no idea about the cross-browser differences, though: that seems inexplicable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't unbind it, just submit it.

```
// $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
this.submit();
```

though, I wonder why you are preventing the submit in the first place if you're just going to submit it anyway.

```
(function ($) {
$(function () {
    eventTracking();
});

function eventTracking() {
    $("[data-formtracking]").bind('submit', function (e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var eventName = $(this).data("formtracking");
        rt.trackEvent(eventName);
        //$(this).unbind('submit').submit();
    });
}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. In Firefox, it required me to click twice to submit. Chrome basically crashed.

Comment: They both work for me. First snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/pagn9/1/  Second snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/pagn9/ Only takes 1 click in firefox, and in chrome it doesn't crash.

Comment: So it's entirely possible, that something in my rt.trackEvent is breaking things and I'm barking up the wrong tree. This successfully submits in all browsers, but the rt.trackEvent() isn't firing properly in FF as there isn't a db entry (but there is for Chrome).

Comment: So the reason for the e.preventDefault and the later submission is that the page was redirecting too quickly. When I step through the code it works in all browsers. When I leave it be, it doesn't work. I used to have a setTimeout($(this).unbind('submit').submit()),1000); to help eleviate this.

Comment: Ah, i see. The best thing in this case is likely going to be making the ajax request within trackEvent synchronous, otherwise it's going to interfere with any other events that may be bound to this or other forms.. Do you control that code?

Comment: The problem is you're going to have to prevent the default action. By doing that though, you're going to screw any other event handling that may already exist on the form because you have no way of knowing (from within trackEvent) if triggering the submit again will cause a double submit.

Comment: As terrible as it sounds, async: false is going to end up being the best way to solve it if you want to keep trackEvent from having to know too much about the form. Otherwise you have to prevent default, and then re-submit it later possibly causing either a double submit, or an unwanted postback.

Answer (score 0):

So not sure if this is the prettiest in the world, but it now works....which is a huge improvment.

```
    $("[data-formtracking]").bind('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        form = this;
        var eventName = $(this).data("formtracking");
        rt.trackEvent(eventName);

        setTimeout(function() {
            form.submit();
        }, 100);
    });
```

Basically, the issue seemed to be with unbinding and resubmit using jquery, so we worked around that and used javascript's submit instead.